# Using csv.writer to write a string to StringIO, why does it add extra characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

How come when I write this string to StringIO the formatting changes?

```
header = '\r\n'.join(
    [unicode(line,'utf8') for line in 
     ['"Text"',
    '"More Text"',
     '',]])
print header
```

Output:

```
"Text"
"More Text"
```

And now adding it to my StringIO:

```
si = StringIO.StringIO()

writer = csv.writer(si)
writer.writerow(header))

si.getvalue()
```

Output:

```
'"""",T,e,x,t,"""","\r","\n","""",M,o,r,e, ,T,e,x,t,"""","\r","\n"\r\n'
```

Why is it adding commas and extra `"` characters?

Comment: It's because header is already a string and then you loop over the characters of that, so just remove the for loop and write header directly to the file

Comment: @SirParselot I see, the reason my non-StringIO code works is because it's writing all the characters with newlines in between but once I write to .csv the newlines all disappear. I'm editing my question with my new problem...

Comment: No I meant the `for line in header` loop. `header` is a string so looping over that will give you each character so `line` is really a single character

Comment: @SirParselot Sorry, it's all confusing now because of my previous example. Let me just remove it. The second code block by itself has no `for` loop but still writes funny.

Comment: well I don't know about  the extra quotes but you can fix most of it by adding `[]` around header since it expects a list

Comment: @SirParselot OK yeah, that makes sense and takes care of the commas. Turns out I can just do `si.write(header)` and everything works, just spent too long coming at the problem from the wrong angle. I'm still curious why it doesn't work with `writer.writerow([header])...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103995/discussion-between-steven-and-sirparselot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `writer.addrow` expects an iterable containing elements and strings an iterables too.

I.e. this code:

```
l = [1,2,3]
for i in l:
    print i
```

will print:

```
1
2
3
```

Same principle applies to strings:

```
s = 'abc'
for c in s:
    print c
```

will print:

```
a
b
c
```

Finally,

```
writer.writerow([1,2,3])   # Gives you 1,2,3
writer.writerow('abc')     # Gives you a,b,c
```

And since `header` is a string in your example, every character in it is treated as separate row. This however, leads to a proper row:

```
writer.writerow(['abc'])   # Gives you abc
```

Finally, many csv dialects use quotes when some elements have delimiters in them, i.e. here first comma is not treated as delimiter because it is located within quotes:

```
writer.writerow(['a,b',3])    # Gives you "a,b",3
```

When quote character itself appears in element, it is also have to be escaped so it won't confuse parser. If [Dialect.doublequote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote) flag is enabled, csv writer will simply double it:

```
writer.writerow(['a",b',3])    # "a"",b",3
```

Comment: Do you know why it is doubling quotes though?

Comment: @SirParselot: Many CSV dialects use quotes for elements with spaces, i.e.: `"1 2",3,"3 4 5"`. So doubling them is a way to escape quotes characters inside a string which is already escaped with quote. It is mentioned in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I didn't pick up on that since there weren't any spaces.

Comment: Great everything makes sense now. I am new with the CSV stuff and it took me long enough to get it working just to get my DataFrame writing properly with a custom header. Then trying to get the same code working for StringIO and nothing was making sense at all.